# How does The Haskell Bind Operator extract the value from monad?

Tags: haskell

Forgive me if the question sounds silly, I'm still a beginner learning Haskell.

Given the bind operator function signature:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

My question is, how does the "a" value get extracted from "m a" so that the function `(a -> m b)` can fire? Does haskell abstract this internally?

Comment: This is done by *implementing* the `(>>=)` function for each `instance` of the `Monad`.

Comment: This thus means that `instance Monad []` will specify `(>>=) = flip concatMap`, whereas `instance Monad Maybe` implements this differently.

Answer (score 7):

This is implemented by the person who writes the `Monad` instance of a specific type.

For example if we look at the `instance` of `Monad` for `Maybe`, [we see [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#instance%20Monad%20Maybe):

> ```
> -- | @since 2.01
> instance  Monad Maybe  where
>     (Just x) >>= k      = k x
>     Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing
>
>     (>>) = (*>)
> ```

whereas for an [instance of the list [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#instance%20Monad%20%5B%5D), we see:

> ```
> -- See Note: [List comprehensions and inlining]
> -- | @since 2.01
> instance Monad []  where
>     {-# INLINE (>>=) #-}
>     xs >>= f             = [y | x <- xs, y <- f x]
>     {-# INLINE (>>) #-}
>     (>>) = (*>)
> ```

If you thus make something an instance of the `Monad` typeclass, you will need to provide an implementation for the `(>>=)` function.

Comment: what does "k" represent in the Maybe Monad example?

Comment: @AndrewTang: `k` is the second parameter (the right operand), if you thus have a `Just 1 >>= (Just . (+1))`, then `k` is the `Just . (+1)` part.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, from the example of the Maybe Monad, it looks like (Just x) can be transformed into k x -- I guess the value within the monad "x" is simply extracted via pattern matching?

Comment: @AndrewTang: yes indeed, although it is up to the implementation of `>>=` to decide what to do. For example `instance Monad []` uses list comprehension with `xs`.

Comment: @AndrewTang: It’s also worth noting that a monadic value of type `m a` doesn’t necessarily “contain” an `a` at all, it’s more like a “source of `a`”. Some instances (like `[]`, `Maybe`, `Either`, `Identity`) are container-like; but others (like `IO`, `Reader`, `Cont`, `Async`, `Parsec`) are more like *actions*. That’s why the perennial beginner question “How do I get the `String` out of an `IO String`?” doesn’t quite make sense, because there is no `String` there: the `IO String` is more like a *program* which can give back a `String`.

Comment: I'll quote the old time favourite: "`getLine :: IO String` contains a `String` in the same way that `/bin/ls` contains a list of files"